# Use reduction of order to find the general solution to $xu''-(x+1)u'+u=0$ where $u_1=x+1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The formula for the second solution is $u=u_1\int \frac{dx}{u_1^2exp(\int{pdx})}$.

Here, $p(x)=-\frac{x+1}{x}=-1-\frac{1}{x}$.

Substituting in to get $$u=(x+1)\int\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2 \cdot exp(-x-ln(x)+C)}$$

$$=(x+1)\int\frac{xdx}{(x+1)^2 \cdot e^{-x} \cdot e^C}$$
$$=E \cdot (x+1)\int\frac{xdx}{(x+1)^2 \cdot e^{-x} }$$

where $E=\frac{1}{e^C}$.

How do I solve this integral? From experience, the outside $(x+1)$ doesn't cancel with the one in the denominator.

The answer from the book is: $u=Ae^x+B(x+1)$, where $A$ and $B$ are some constants.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$I=\int e^x \frac{x}{(x+1)^2}dx=\int e^{x} \frac {x+1-1}{(1+x)^2}dx=
\int e^x \left( \frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}\right) dx =\frac{e^x}{1+x}.$$ Use $$\int e^x [f(x)+f'(x)]dx= e^x f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Writing $x$ in the numerator as $ (x+1)-x$ we see that $\int \frac {xe^{x}} {(x+1)^{2}}\, dx= \int \frac {e^{x}} {x+1}\, dx -\int \frac {e^{x}} {(x+1)^{2}}\, dx$. In the first term integrate by parts. We get $\int \frac {e^{x}} {x+1}\, dx =e^{x} \frac 1 {x+1} + \int \frac {e^{x}} {(x+1)^{2}}\, dx$. There is a cancellation now and you get the answer easily.